# Can we interpret Reinhardt cardinals this way?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, embeddings

To the language of set theory add a primitive unary predicate $\operatorname {Universe}$ and a primitive total unary function $j$. Add all axioms of $\sf ZF$ in the language of this theory, i.e. the new primitives allowed to be used in instances of Separation and Replacement, I'll refer to this simply as $\sf ZFj$.

We add the following axioms:

**Cumulative:** $\forall X: \operatorname {Universe}(X) \to \exists \lambda: X=V_\lambda$

**Modeling:** if $\psi$ is an axiom of $\sf ZFj$, and $\psi^X$ is the $``\in X"$ bounded form of $\psi$; then:  $$\forall X: \operatorname {Universe}(X) \to \psi^X$$

**Elementarity:** if $\phi(x_1,..,x_n)$ is a formula in signature $\{=,\in\}$, having $``x_1,..,x_n\! \!"$ as its sole free variables, and none of them occur bound, then: $$\forall X: \operatorname {Universe}(X) \to\forall x \in X \, (j(x) \in X) \land \\\forall x_1,..,x_n \in X \\ (\phi(x_1,..,x_n) \iff \phi(j(x_1),..,j(x_n))) \\ \land \exists x \in X: j(x) \neq x$$

The intention is to render the restriction of $j$ to any Universe $X$ a non-trivial elementary embedding from $X \to X$.

**Reflection:** if $\phi$ is a formula [defined functions and predicates allowed] not using the symbol $X$, and $\phi^X$ is the $``\in X"$ bounded form of $\phi$; then: $$\forall \vec{p} \, (\phi \to \exists X: \operatorname {Universe} (X) \land \phi^X)$$

> Is this consistent? If so, what's its consistency strength?

> In particular does it manage to interpret Reinhardt cardinals at each universe? Would we have a club of Reinhardt cardinals?

Comment: Seems like a really overengineered way to state there is a lot of I3 cardinals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, why the universes do not manage to capture Reinhardt cardinals?

Comment: You're just saying a lot $V_\lambda$ have elementary embeddings to itself.

Comment: @AsafKaragila but $V_\lambda$ models $\sf ZFj$, that is $j$ is used in replacement. So, how is that different from the Reinhardt's cardinal situation.

Comment: @FarmerS, let's take an example, take $\phi$
 to be the formula $\exists q ( j(p)=q)$
 then by reflection we'll have $(\exists X: \operatorname {Universe}(X) \land \exists q \in X ( j(p)=q))$
. I couldn't see the problem of non-well-definiteness? $j$ is a primitive symbol of the language. Can you please explain this point?

Comment: @FarmerS, I'm not really fully sure if I'm properly following you here. But let me at least explain my notation: $\phi^X$ here just mean that all quantifiers in $\phi$ be relativized to  $X$, i.e. followed by $``\in X"$.  I don't know why I feel that you think that $\phi^X$ means $X \models \phi$, it does not! It only means that all quantifiers in $\phi$ are bounded in $X$ that's all, otherwise everything in $\phi$ remains unchanged in $\phi^X$, so the symbols $\{=, \in, \operatorname {Universe};j\}$ keep their original positions, i.e. they are not syntactically manipulated... cont.

Comment: @FarmerS... continuation: $\phi^X$ is syntactically well defined, there is no problem with it, it doesn't beg any interpretation at all, it is simple relativization of quantifiers.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I missed that description; I was indeed thinking that $\phi^X$ meant $X\models\phi$. However, there is this notation in the "Modeling" axiom. So is that supposed to be $(\mathrm{ZF}_j)^X$?

Comment: @FarmerS, well originally I meant for it to be the single sentence stating that $X$ is a model of $\sf ZFj$ which means $(X, \in \restriction X, j \restriction X) \models \sf ZFj$. But anyhow that is not needed, I think its enough for it to be $\sf (ZFj)^X$, where it would render it a schema for each axiom of $\sf ZFj$. I'll edit it. Thanks!

Comment: @AsafKaragila it is not exactly "a lot of I3 cardinals", as "Elementarity" requires all of the elementary embeddings to extends each other

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar why do you think you would get any Reinhardt cardinals? You don't have any elementarity with formulaes with $j$. This theory is either not much stronger than $I2$, weaker than $I2$ or inconsistent because of the reflection property

Comment: @Holo, you mean Reinhardt's cardinals require existence of elementary embeddings from $V \to V$ in signature $\{=,\in, j\}$? So, in the Elementarity axiom schema I need $\phi(x_1,..,x_n)$ to be written in signature $\{=,\in, j\}$, just a question. I don't see people stating exactly the language of those embeddings when presenting Reinhardt cardinals, I thought the embeddings are in the lanugage of set theory.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar yes, for Reinhardt you need nee in the language of $\{∈,j\}$. If you have nee in the language of $\{∈\}$ you get a [wholeness cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wholeness_axiom), ([see also](https://web.archive.org/web/20220818235315/http://cantorsattic.info/Wholeness_axioms)), which are weaker than $I3$ (I believe that the question of whether full wholeness axiom is strictly weaker than $I3$ or is it equivalent is open)

Comment: @Holo, OK. Thanks. I'll edit it the question accordingly

Comment: @Zuhair: In Elementarity, perhaps you do now want to allow j to occur in . As it is 
there must be a least ordinal κ with j(k)≠κ. Then ∀y(y∈κ-->j(y)=y). By elementarity
∀y(y∈j(κ)-->j(y)=y). But this is not true when y is κ.

Comment: @GregKirmayer, yes you are right! It appears that my original formulation was the correct one. Reinhardt cardinals only require nee of V to V in $=,\in$ signature. If we extend the signature to include $j$ then we get the inconsistency you mentioned.

Comment: @Holo, are you sure that elementarity requires the nee to be in signature {∈,j} , it appears that this is inconsistent. It appears that Reinhardt cardinal doesn't require nee to be in {∈,j} it only requires it to be in {∈}, the wholeness axiom is weaker than Reinhardt cardinals because it doesn't allow replacement for j-formulas, not because it doesn't allow j in elementarity. Here, in this theory the reason why we get Reinhardt is because we do have Replacement for j-formulas. Actually that's what the link you referred is saying. Kunen's inconsistency speaks about nee in signature {∈}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is inconsistent. Call an ordinal b an independent critical point if for every for every Universe X,

if c∈X then there is a function f with domain X and an ordinal α, such that "f is an elementary

embedding from X to Vα" holds, for all x∈X f(x)∈X, and b is the least ordinal with f(b)≠b.

Note that the critical point of j is an independent critical point because the restriction of j to any

Universe X has the above property of f.  Let c be the least independent critical point. By the

axiom schema of Reflection, there is a universe K such that "c is the least independent critical

point" holds relativized to K. By the definition of independent critical point, there is a function

g with domain K and ordinal γ such tha g is an elementary embedding from K to Vγ, and for all x∈K g(x)∈K

and c is the least ordinal with g(c)≠c. Let F(x) be a formula expressing

"x is the least independent critical point". Define a sequence s by

s0=c and s(n+1) is the least ordinal α such that α is greater than g(s(n)) and for K, Vα reflects all

subformulas of F. Let t=U{sn|n∈}. Then g(t)=t, and F(c) holds in V(t).  By elementarity,F(g(c)) holds

in V(g(t)). That is F(g(c)) holds in V(t). But this is impossible.